# PHP output displays garbage

Tags: php, html

I've seen a few cases of this online but every solution I try yields the same result. I have tried various versions of this same bit of code but I still am unable to display an image, either from the internet or from a folder.

**My code looks like this:**

```
    <?php
    $img = 'anything.jpg';
    $getInfo = getimagesize($img);
    header('Content-type: ' . $getInfo['mime']);
    readfile($img);
    ?>
```

And then this in the appropriate spot in the html document:

```
<?php
echo "<img src ='$img'>";
?>
```

**My output looks like this:** *(only it is about 100 lines long, covering most of the page)*

```
„•J€m’¥Id„©,ƒð‹"È!dY*   
d¨E„Œœ6TêÞ BTç–dáfÎ´§ÝfÎ°É¾,ÙÔÌxà5IõcÁ=£TM´® ‡iNt4ÖMYí;ÅU©ª’§ª7’Ê:¡ú§šß”,¾5™ˆ
```

**The image displays after all this.**
I've been working at this quite a while now, any help would make a man's day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem using the following code:

```
<?php
$img = 'anything.png';
header("Content-type:image/png");
imagepng($img);
?>

<?php
echo "<img src ='$img'>";
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

The `content-type` of the image is in the array under `mime`, not `img`.

```
header('Content-type: ' . $getInfo['mime']);
```

More info is available in the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/getimagesize).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I fixed that. I was hopeful but unfortunately it didn't solve my error.

Comment: Your code to output the image is all that's in that file, right? And the HTML document is separate? Where in that page is `$img` defined? Is it just the URL of the first script?